# Помощь с разъяснением кода

Tags: java, консоль

Есть задание, оно уже решено и работает как нужно при вводе с клавиатуры, но код задания автоматически предлагает проверку без использования клавиатуры.
Что делает эта строчка кода?

```
System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(
  "char^String^int^double^stop".replace("^", System.lineSeparator()).getBytes(ENCODING)));
Part3.main(args);
```

После этого, насколько я понимаю, следует строка восстановления стандартного потока ввода:

```
System.setIn(STD_IN);
```

Answer (score 2):

Посылает на вход

```
char
String
int
double
stop
```

как если бы вы ввели это с клавиатуры. Сначала каждый символ "^" заменяется на символ переноса строки, который берется из "System.lineSeparator()", потом все это  преобразуется в байт массив с текущей кодировкой "getBytes(ENCODING)", этот массив передается конструктору "ByteArrayInputStream", который устанавливается как поток ввода

Comment: Как мне взять то что оно туда посылает? вот в чём вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось всё очень просто что бы получить все эти данные которые посылаются в поток ввода достаточно вычитать внутри main поток ввода через массив и далее его уже обрабатывать как нужно.